# Inplace lexically sorting a partitioned list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I have the following problem: I have a collection of (name, grade) pairs of data coming e.g. from a battery of tests in which the persons took part;
what I now want to do is to

- have each person's grades sorted in ascending order
- have the persons sorted in ascending lexical order of their sorted grade-sequences

(How) can that be achieved inplace sorting of a python list that contains the (name,grade) pairs?

Example:
BeforeI have

```
>>> list((['John', 1],['John', 2],['John', 3],
          ['Jane', 1],['Jane', 1],['Jane', 4],
          ['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],
          ['Bob', 2],['Bob', 3],['Bob', 3]))
```

and I want to reorder to get

```
>>>list((['Jane', 1],['Jane', 1],['Jane', 4],
         ['John', 1],['John', 2],['John', 3],
         ['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],
         ['Bob', 2],['Bob', 3],['Bob', 3]))
```

And the question amounts to how to define the 'key', resp. 'cmp' keyword arguments of list.sort to accomplish that.

Comment: Couple questions: in your output, the names aren't listed in the lexicographic order. So how would you want them listed? Typo maybe? Also, are the names in the input list always grouped? i.e. can you ever have John, John, Alice, John? Or only John, John, John, Alice... etc. Finally, by in place, do you mean in like one line? No extra loops?

Comment: @atru there is no typo in the desired ordering of the tuples and inplace means not using any extra space for storing intermediate results.

Comment: @superbrain sorry for the glitch of forgetting the brackets for the list argument and not checking for valid syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not quite inplace, but I think its close enough, and is concise while still readable:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

data = [['John', 1],['John', 2],['John', 3],['Jane', 1],['Jane', 1],['Jane', 4],['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],['Bob', 2],['Bob', 3],['Bob', 3]]

groups = []
data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: x[0])
for _, g in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0]):
    groups.append(sorted(list(g), key = lambda x: x[1]))

output = list(chain(*sorted(groups, key = lambda x: ('').join([str(y[1]) for y in x]))))
```

The code uses [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the names together, at (almost) the same time sorting them by score to meet your first requirement. The input to `groupby` has to be sorted already, hence the first sort.

After that the code sorts whole groups by the lexical value created by combining all the scores in each group. After sorting, `output` is created by flattening the nested list with groups using `chain`.

Comment: I guess that comes closest to what I was looking for and more important, it is nicely explained

Answer (score 0):

```
grades = ['John', 1],['John', 2],['John', 3],['Jane', 1],['Jane', 1],['Jane', 4],['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],['Bob', 2],['Bob', 3],['Bob', 3]

names_used = []
lst=[]
for x in grades:
    sub_list = []
    for y in grades:
        if x[0] == y[0] and x[0] not in names_used:
            sub_list.append(y)
    names_used.append(x[0])

    if sub_list != []:
        lst.append(sorted(sub_list))

new = []
for i in range(4):
    n = []
    for item in lst:
        if item[0][1] == i:
            n.append(item)
    new = new+sorted(n)

final_list = [data for tup in new for data in tup]
print(final_list)


>>> [['Jane', 1], ['Jane', 1], ['Jane', 4], ['John', 1], ['John', 2], ['John', 3], ['Alice', 2], ['Alice', 2], ['Alice', 2], ['Bob', 2], ['Bob', 3], ['Bob', 3]]
```

First group grades of the same name into sublists

Now create a loop that loops till the maximum grade, and for each grades creates a temporary list which adds the sublist where the minimum grade for that person is number for that loop, then add the `sorted` version of this temporary list to the parent list `new`, (`sorted` puts the list in **lexical** order).

Then finally use a list comprehension to get rid of the tuples

Answer (score 0):

**This should rather be seen as a remark:**

if the objective is report the ranking on basis of the person's lexicographically sorted sequence of grades in a compact way, then that can be achieved by a variant of Gödel numbers: map each grade-value to a unique prime and set as a person's rank the product of its prime-ranks, sorting the persons according to that rank yields the sought original order:

```
primes = list((      
      2,     3,     5,     7,    11,    13,    17,    19,    23,    29,
     31,    37,    41,    43,    47,    53,    59,    61,    67,    71,
     73,    79,    83,    89,    97,   101,   103,   107,   109,   113,
    127,   131,   137,   139,   149,   151,   157,   163,   167,   173,
    179,   181,   191,   193,   197,   199,   211,   223,   227,   229,
    233,   239,   241,   251,   257,   263,   269,   271,   277,   281,
    283,   293,   307,   311,   313,   317,   331,   337,   347,   349,
))

grades = list((['John', 1],['John', 2],['John', 3],
          ['Jane', 1],['Jane', 1],['Jane', 4],
          ['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],['Alice', 2],
          ['Bob', 2],['Bob', 3],['Bob', 3]))  
code = dict()
for x in grades:
    if x[0] in code:
        code[x[0]] *= primes[x[1]]
    else:
        code[x[0]] = primes[x[1]]
    
rank = sorted(list(code.items()),key=lambda x:x[1])
```

That algorithm is only of theoretical interest because it also is capable of calculating the ranking of persons from an unsorted list of grades even with à priory unknown set of people, set of grades and number of tests which is the situation if the data comes from an input stream.
If the set of grades is small, then a fixed list of primes will suffice; otherwise additional primes have to be generated and of course the cost for infinite-precision multiplication of the primes and the footprint for storing these products will have severe impact on its usability beyond toy-examples.